# Angularjs scope variable not updating as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yVnuWp?p=preview) Preview of the problem.

**Index.html**

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

Master Checkbox : <input type="checkbox" id="allSelected" ng-click="checkAll('allSelected')"  ng-checked="allChecked"> <br> <br>

Slave1 : <input type="checkbox" id="slave1" ng-click="checkAll('slave1')" ng-checked="selectedAll" > <br>
Slave2 : <input type="checkbox" id="slave2" ng-click="checkAll('slave2')" ng-checked="selectedAll" > <br>
Slave3 : <input type="checkbox" id="slave3" ng-click="checkAll('slave3')" ng-checked="selectedAll" > <br>
Slave4 : <input type="checkbox" id="slave4" ng-click="checkAll('slave4')" ng-checked="selectedAll" > <br>
Slave5 : <input type="checkbox" id="slave5" ng-click="checkAll('slave5')" ng-checked="selectedAll" > <br>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkAll = function(id) {

    // First Condition
    if (id === "allSelected" && document.getElementById(id).checked) {
     // $scope.selectedAll = false;
      $scope.allChecked = true;
      $scope.selectedAll = true;
    }

    // Second Condition
    if (id === "allSelected" && !document.getElementById(id).checked) {
      $scope.allChecked = false;
      $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }

    // Third Condition
    if (id !== "allSelected" && !document.getElementById(id).checked) {
      $scope.allChecked = false;

    }


  };
});
```

See the *First Condition*. It is not working as expected.

I'm uploading images here for a better understanding of the problem.

[image: This is working as expected but after this]

[image: this is not working as expected]

Checkout the difference between first image and second image. After unchecking any of the slave checkbox, the master checkbox is getting unchecked but just after that when you click the master checkbox again(see the second image) that particular salve checkbox is still unchecked. Why?

What I'm doing here is wrong? How to make this code working as expected?

Comment: you are using angularjs, why do you check it with element's id, is checked or not.You can do it with $SCOPE variables, and 2 ways binding will solve your problems

Comment: @ngDeveloper I got it but can you elaborate or show me some example because I'm new to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote your example:

**html:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Master Checkbox : <input type="checkbox" id="allSelected" ng-click="checkAll()" ng-model="masterCheckbox"> <br> <br>

    <div ng-repeat="checkbox in checkBoxes">
      {{checkbox.name}} : <input type="checkbox" id="slave5" ng-click="check(checkbox)" ng-model="checkbox.value" /> <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.checkBoxes = [
        { name:'Slave1', value: false },
        { name:'Slave2', value: false },
        { name:'Slave3', value: false },
        { name:'Slave4', value: false },
        { name:'Slave5', value: false }
    ];

    $scope.checkAll = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.checkBoxes, function(item){
            item.value = $scope.masterCheckbox;
        });
    };

    $scope.check = function() {
        var result = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.checkBoxes, function(item){
            if(!item.value) result = false;
        });
        $scope.masterCheckbox = result;
    };
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3298/)

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the wrong way. In angular input values are stored/retrieved using `ng-model`, i recommend you read up on it either on the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_model.asp). The basic idea is that when you set the ng-model of an input, angular itself keeps track of the input value and updates it on change (so there's no need for the id on the checkbox).

try changing your master checkbox to:

```
Master Checkbox : <input ng-change="selectAll(allSelected)" type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected">
```

and the other checkboxes to:

```
Slave 1: <input ng-change="unselect()" type="checkbox" ng-model="slave.selected"></br>
/// etc.
```

Also i like to point out that when you have repeated checkboxes (the slave checkboxes in your example), usually you wouldn't list them all in the html, you would create an array in your controller then just use an [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to output all checkboxes. Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/w50WALj4Y0MtVVYX5TaV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

Master Checkbox : <input type="checkbox" id="allSelected" ng-click="checkAll()"  ng-model="allChecked"> <br> <br>

Slave1 : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checboxes['slave1']"> <br>
Slave2 : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checboxes['slave2']"> <br>
Slave3 : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checboxes['slave3']"> <br>
Slave4 : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checboxes['slave4']"> <br>
Slave5 : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checboxes['slave5']"> <br>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    if($scope.allChecked){
      for(var i in $scope.checkboxes){
        $scope.checkboxes[i] = true;
      }
    }
  };
});
```